# How to show paginated results for the category items of the selected category in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, paginator

Currently i'm having a problem with the pagination of some results. The problem is the following:

I have a website with 3 tables: categories, categories_companies and companies. In a many-to-many relationship. When i select one category, it shows the companies that belongs to the selected category. My problem is here! I don't know how to make it to show only 10 companies per category.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

did you read this?

```
class RecipesController extends AppController {

    var $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
}
```